# How can I install ipython notebook on ubuntu 17?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython

I tried to install ipython notebook on my OS.But there was an error.How can I solve this?

```
sudo apt-get install ipython-notebook
```

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ipython-notebook is not available, but is referred to by another packag.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ipython-notebook' has no installation candidate

Comment: In some cases this problem can be solved by running the command `apt-get update`. because apt or apt-get  doesn't know about what you're talking about and can be solved by updating. Let me know if it worked for you or not .

Comment: `pip install ipython` or `sudo apt-get install ipython` and similar things should go for python3

Answer (score 5):

Do you already have python installed? If so, try:

`sudo apt-get install ipython`

or if you have pip:

`pip install ipython ipython-notebook`

Regardless, I instead recommend installing Anaconda or Miniconda from:

https://www.continuum.io/downloads

This will help you setup virtual environments and packages.

Comment: `Anaconda` contains all library that is useful.In `IPython` you have to install different-different libraries.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm using Docker. Got this error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipython-notebook (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ipython-notebook

Answer (score 5):

I installed `ipython` via `apt`, and then went the `pip` and `virtualenvwrapper` route for `ipython-notebook`, which worked for me. The commands were:

`sudo apt -y install ipython
mkvirtualenv ipynb
pip install ipython[notebook]`

Alternatively:

`sudo apt -y install ipython
mkvirtualenv ipynb
pip install ipython[all]`

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I ran into this error when trying to run the following command on a freshly spun up Ubuntu 18 image (on AWS, ami-0ac019f4fcb7cb7e6):

```
sudo apt-get install ipython3
```

> E: Package 'ipython3' has no installation candidate

Running an apt-get update solved the problem. So:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ipython3
```

Interestingly, I was surprised to find that this particular distro doesn't come with Python 2.7 installed, only Python3.  That's probably AWS just trying to keep things light, which I appreciate.

Hopefully this helps someone down the line.

Answer (score -1):

As virtually every Linux distro, Ubuntu comes with Python 2.7 pre-installed. In order to execute your Python code, you open your terminal, cd to the directory where the script is and run `python script.py`